# iOS app build with Adobe AIR SDK 24 crashes when trying to use permissions

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I have an adobe AIR app developed for iOS devices and I use Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 to create the .ipa file.

Up to version 23 of the AIR SDK the app was working fine. With version 24 of the AIR SDK a Permissions class was added when trying to access the device camera. And now one should programmatically handle the permissions when accessing the camera as follows: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2250328

I have tried implementing the given example in my codebase, and in the following snippet, I have null references to the permissions as follows:

```
   private function connect():void {      
        if (Camera.permissionStatus/*permissionStatus is null*/ != PermissionStatus.GRANTED)
        {       
                  cam.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS,
                    function(e:PermissionEvent):void {
                        if (e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
                            connectCamera();
                        } else {
                            // permission denied
                        }
                    });

                try {
                    cam.requestPermission(); // **when calling this one my app crashes**
                } catch(e:Error) {
                    // another request is in progress
                }
         } else {
              connectCamera();
         }
    }

    private function connectCamera():void
    {
        video = new Video(640, 480);
        video.attachCamera(cam);
        addChild(video);
    }
```

My hunch is that when debugging on the device the Flash Builder is using the flex sdk instead of the AIR SDK which makes the aforementioned properties/methods unavailable as stated in the SDK documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html where one can see that the permissionStatus method is only available for the AIR runtime.

Therefore, how can I check and make sure that I am debugging using the AIR runtime and eventually avoid my app to crash when asking the user for camera permissions.

Comment: I had performance issues with Starling + AIR 24 and there was a related thread on Starling forum ( http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/air-24-performance-issues ) so it is not just my imagination. It is possible that AIR 24 is a bad release in many ways and you might want to revert to AIR 23 instead of looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2264992

> Kindly include cocoa keys under  tag in app.xml For
>   Example, If you are trying to access the Camera in your application,
>   you need to include below tag under 
>   NSCameraUsageDescription "SOME TEXT"
>   Please refer to below link for detailed information on cocoa keys:
>   [Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)